# Tension between two masses connected by a massles rod

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics

I'm interested in the following problem. We have two particles in the plane, with masses $m_X$ and $m_Y$. Their positions, $X,Y$ satisfy the constraint $|X-Y| = L$. There is an external force field for each particle, $F_X,F_Y$. Now, the constraint implies that there is a tension between the two particles, $F_T$. So the equations of motion are $$m_X\ddot{X} = F_X+F_T$$ $$m_Y\ddot{Y} = F_Y-F_T$$ My question is how can $F_T$ be calculated if the velocities and external forces are given?

Comment: See this - [Why is the tension on both sides of an Atwood machine identical?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/594577/37364)

Comment: That's not what OP asked for. From the provided equations, it's clear that OP is aware that the magnitude of the force exerted by the massless rod is the same on each mass.

Comment: @user256872 Op has asked solution to the problem which is wrong so it is better for him/her to read the working

Comment: Voting to close as this is a homework type question.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

I didn't quite understand the notations you used in your question but I think this is what you're looking for.

Have a nice day :)

Comment: , This is an answer to homework like question. Also it is complete answer just like spoon,feeding please refrain from this type of activities.

Comment: @user91594, Yeah I'll keep that in mind from now on. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Your assumption is indeed true. It is calculus based term so you can remove  the word assumption now

Comment: Can you explain what that actually means? It's not possible to copy paste that term into google search. I don't even know what's it called. What I studied is $\mathbf a$ = $\frac{\delta \mathbf v}{\delta \mathbf t}$ in calculus. Would really love to know another form to write this in.

Comment: Single dot above terms means first derivative and two means second deravitive. Now a is second deravitive of X so two dots. These are used just to save time(you know how lazy physicists are)

Comment: Hi Jeeshaan, thanks for your answer, but the problem is in 2D. Indeed, in 1D it is easy to calculate.

Comment: Also, im not sure you solved it. you just expressed Ft in terms of acceleration which is not known directly. Also,  Fx isn't equal to Fy