# When we push a box, the box applies an opposite force on my hand, but why does my hand move with the box as I push the box if the net force of it 0?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram

When we push a box, the box applies an opposite force on my hand, but why does my hand move with the box as I push the box if the net force of is 0?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Given Newton's third law, why are things capable of moving?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/45653/)

Comment: Possible duplicate by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/604251/2451

Comment: "the net force of is 0". This is ambiguous. Are you talking about the force acting on your hand or the force on the box or the force on the hand+box treated as a single thing?

Answer (score 0):

If you consider frictional force to be 0, then even the slightest force would cause any body to move forward.
The equation would be as such:

F = ma

Where 'F' is the force applied, 'm' is mass of the box pushed, and 'a' is the acceleration of the box due to the force applied.

Now, if you want to consider that the box applies a equal and opposite force to the hand, then you **have** to consider the 'hand and block' system to be moving together, so that pseudo-forces won't be considered. But in reality, the block will not apply an equal reaction, that is why the block moves forward with an acceleration.