# Forces in an elastic 1D collision

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws, collision

Let's say I have block **A** (5kg, a = 10 $\frac{m}{s^2}$) and block **B** (20kg, a = 20 $\frac{m}{s^2}$). When they collide together elastically, the forces exerted on each other should be the same by Newton's third law. My question is: what is the value of this equal and opposite force?

When block A collides with B, can we say it exerts $F = 5 * 10 = 50N$. Similarly when block B collides with A, it exerts $F = 20 * 20 = 400N$. Can we conclude that the equal and opposite force is $450N$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you have set up this question makes it a little unclear.

You have two blocks with different masses and accelerations. You can calculate the forces, and they are different. Perhaps you have two different blocks with two different ropes on them. You pull on the ropes and the objects accelerate.

Forces always occur in equal and opposite pairs. If you pull on a rope to accelerate an object toward yourself, the rope also pulls on you toward the object. See [Why is the tension on both sides of an Atwood machine identical?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/594577/37364)

The situation is different when the objects collide. They exert equal and opposite forces on each other. Often people don't ask about the forces during a collision. Collisions are usually brief. People often just ask about velocity before and after and show energy and momentum are conserved.

Sometimes they do ask. For hard objects like golf clubs and golf balls, the collision can be over in microseconds. The balls had a large change in velocity in a very short time. This means very large forces were applied for that short time. The manufactureres of golf balls and golf clubs want to know the details of those forces. [The Moment of Impact. An Inside Look at Titleist Golf Ball R&D](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6TA1s1oNpbk)

From the video, it is obvious that a very large force was applied to the golf ball. The golf ball deformed and accelerated.

The video didn't make this clear, but the force on the golf club at each instant during the collision was equal and opposite to the force on the ball. The club is harder, so it deformed less. The head of the club is more massive, moving, and has additional forces from the shaft acting on it. So the change in velocity is both smaller and harder to see.