# Block on block problem, but with variable acceleration

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction, free-body-diagram

Consider this setup. A block of mass $m$ sits on another one of mass $M$ which is on a frictionless surface and friction is present between the two blocks. Let the maximum value of static friction be $f_{static}$. Now, I apply a force $F<f_{static}$ on the top block. What will be the motion of the system? Intuitively, I think it to be $\frac {F}{M+m}$, but cannot derive it mathematically. Note that there is no restriction on the motion of the blocks relative to each other.

P.S.- This is the question I originally had in mind while posting the recent posts, but everytime I framed the wrong question.

Comment: Which block is F applied to?

Comment: @BobD See my edit.

Comment: Where is the edit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $F < f_{static}$ then both blocks move with the same acceleration $a$, so we have

$F = (M+m)a 
\\ \displaystyle \Rightarrow a = \frac F {M+m}$

But this is the same question as you asked [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/623174/in-a-system-of-stacked-blocks-with-friction-how-can-the-top-block-have-no-accel). Possibly you intend to ask about the scenario $F > f_{static}(1+\frac m M)$, when the frictional force between the blocks is limited to its maximum value $f_{static}$ and the blocks move with different accelerations ?

**Edited to clarify forces acting on each block**:

If the blocks accelerate with the same acceleration $a$ then the force of friction between them is

$\displaystyle f_{friction} = Ma = \frac {MF}{M+m}$

and the net force on the top block is

$\displaystyle F - f_{friction} = F - \frac {MF}{M+m} = \frac {mF}{M+m} = ma$

Comment: But why does they need to have same accelerations? I can't understand it mathematically.

Comment: the net force on the upper block is $0$.

Comment: @Feynstein As long as the maximum static friction force is not exceeded the blocks accelerate together. The net force on the upper block is not zero. I explained this in my answer to the link provided by gandalf61.

Comment: @BobD But how to **prove** that the two accelerations are equal if max static friction is not exceeded?

Comment: @Feynstein If the max static friction force is not exceeded the top block sticks to the bottom block. With no friction on the surface, the two blocks are subjected to a net external horizontal force of F. The acceleration is a=F/(m+M). What don't you understand about that?

Comment: @BobD What are the equations that says they stick together? Isn't it that F-f=0?

Comment: @Feynstein I think your problem is you think the friction force between the blocks cancels the applied force to the top block for a net force of zero.  It does not.  If the maximum static friction force is not exceeded there is no relative motion between the top and bottom blocks, so they must move together with the same acceleration. Then to determine the force on each block you need to do a FBD applying Newton 2 to each with the understanding that each has the same acceleration relative to the frame of reference of the supporting surface.

Comment: @BobD Why cannot they cancel? They are **equal and opposite**!

Comment: @Feynstein They are not equal and opposite. The friction force on the top block is equal and opposite the friction force on the bottom block. Taking the blocks together, those forces are INTERNAL forces. But each friction force acts as an EXTERNAL force on each block per the FBD on each block. I'm sorry I can't make this any clearer, so I'm signing off. Good luck.

Comment: @Feynstein For what it's worth, you are not alone thinking they cancel. This has come up numerous times. That's why it is so important to use free body diagrams. Look again at my previous answer. An old mechanics professor of mine uses to say over and over DRAW A FREE BODY DIAGRAM! Ciou.

Comment: @Feynstein We have already covered this. The top block cannot remain at rest while the lower block moves. If $F=f_{friction}$ then $a=0$ for both blocks and so $F=0$. For other items you should post a new question.