# Tension in string in Atwood's machine

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, string

[image]

Consider the above Atwood's machine consisting of ideal pulley and string. I learnt from other answers on this site that Tension at every point on string will be equal. However I cannot prove it for a small piece of string in touch with pulley.

I drew it's FBD as follows-

[image]

However I'm not able to prove that tension at both ends will be equal with this diagram.

Can you help me understand it?

Comment: [Why is the tension on both sides of an Atwood machine identical?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/594577/37364)

Comment: @mmesser314 The link doesn't answers what I'm asking, I'm asking how to do the procedure for the segment which is in contact with pulley?

Comment: "*I would like to question you here, the normal force between pulley and rope will be zero, see here*" It depends what you mean by zero. If you're saying that sum of the force vector in the rope FBD and the pulley FBD is zero then yes, of course it is. It has to be since they are static relative to one another. Just like how the internal force in a rope under tension sums up to zero or how the sum of the force on your feet and the ground is zero. If it weren't then the two pieces would be accelerating away from the other.

Answer (score 1):

In general, tensions will **not** be equal. But it is usually assumed that the rope is an ideal one, and this means that it has zero mass, among other things. So when you write Newton's 2nd Law for the rope (or a little piece of it) you get $T_1 - T_2 = 0 \textrm{ kg} \, a = 0 \textrm{ N} \implies T_1 = T_2$

Comment: How do you account for that normal force

Comment: It is compensated by the normal component of gravitational force (say $m g \cos {\alpha} $, if you know what I mean) but again, if you assume that the rope has no mass, there's no need to take it into consideration

Comment: @therefore Rope doesn't pushes pulley neither pulley pushes rope in case the rope is massless

Comment: please see above comment

Comment: How could the tensions on the two halves of the rope not be equal? That would mean that the internal force is not equal which would cause the two parts of the rope to be accelerating away from (or toward) each other.

Comment: @lalit right, that follows from Newton 2nd Law for the normal direction: $N - m g \cos {\alpha} = m \, a_n$ with $m=0$

Comment: @DKNguyen the OP is asking about 2 tensions acting on a small piece of the rope, not the tensions on the two halves (at least that is what I was talking about)

Comment: @DKNguyen although even if we are talking about tensions in both halves, they do not need to be equal. Consider the case where the pulley has angular acceleration

Answer (score 0):

The pulley and string are ideal. That means they are massless and the pulley is frictionless.

The purpose of this idealization is to make the problem easier. It allows you to focus on the forces from gravity and tension. The pulley doesn't change the tension in the string. It just bends the string around it. The key point is that it takes no force to accelerate a massless pulley and string.

This post shows how to calculate the tension in the string for a tug of war. [Why is the tension on both sides of an Atwood machine identical?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/594577/37364). We can take the idea a step farther.

Suppose you have a tug of war with three people, two of whom don't pull. One person is in the middle with two ropes leading in opposite directions. You can do an analysis like in that post to calculate the tension in the two ropes.

If you set the middle mass to $0$, you will find the two tensions are equal, as if the middle mass wasn't there. This should help you see that a massive pulley would make the tensions on the two sides different, but a massless one will have no effect.

---

Conceptually, you can think of the string as little short chain links, each pulling on the next.

As the string wraps around the pulley, successive links form a slight angle. The forces of tension on a junction of two links are not quite aligned, and do not quite cancel.

Consider a "chain" of the first two links. One hanging straight down, and the one above it at a slight angle. The forces on the ends of the chain pull the chain toward the pulley. The pulley is rigid, and pushes back hard enough to keep the string from pushing into its surface. This force is perpendicular to the surface of the pulley.

You can find similar perpendicular outward forces from the pulley all around the upper half of the pulley. By symmetry, you can see that any force to the left is balanced by a force to the right. The upward force holds the masses up. The total is less than the total weight of the two masses. There is a net downward acceleration.

The important point about the forces being perpendicular to the pulley are that they do not pull along the string. They don't accelerate the string either left or right. Thus, they hold the string up without changing the tension or the acceleration of the two masses.

Comment: Ok , so I understand if in place of that second person, we would have a pulley then tension on both sides of it would be same but How can I visualize this in case of atwood's machine where all are not in straight line

Comment: I understand your point completely and I also had a discussion with a very reputed member of this community( https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54160/problem-solving-strategies ) but I don't understand why those vertical components would add up to $(m_1+m_2)g$ can You please include that math into your answer

Comment: I didn't do the math. I expected the upward force would cancel the downward force of the weight. Now that I think about it, that is wrong.

Comment: I'm not able to only grasp the fact that if masses on either side of pulley are unequal and the tension in rope is T , then why force on pulley downwards will be 2T

Comment: Does it make sense if the masses are equal and $T = mg$? Does it make sense if the masses are almost equal, and $T$ is between $m_1g$ and $m_2g$?

Comment: Does it make sense if $m_2 = 0$ and $T = 0$?

Comment: Yes I'm able to visualize all the cases

Comment: How can you explain that upwards hold masses up