# Forces acting on the force sensor in the accelerated reference frame

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, acceleration, free-body-diagram, home-experiment

I am doing a thought experiment in which two bodies are rigidly connected to each other and my force sensor is rigidly located between these two bodies. My system accelerates and brakes at regular intervals. Now I am wondering what the force sensor is measuring.

On the one hand, of course, the resulting force

$F_{resulting}=m_{system}\cdot a_{system}$

from the acceleration and deceleration of my system. On the other hand, since my sensor is in the accelerated system, inertial forces which, depending on the braking and acceleration of the system, result either from
$F_I=-(m_{body1}+m_{sensor})\cdot a$ respectively $F_I=-(m_{body2}+m_{sensor})\cdot a$
respectively.

I am now asking myself, do I measure $F_{resulting}-F_{I}$, or do I only measure $F_{I}$?

Maybe someone here has some advice for me?

Comment: This may help. [Why is the tension on both sides of an Atwood machine identical?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/594577/37364). Your case would be like a tug of war with a person in the middle where only one person on the end pulls.

Comment: But what is the sensor measuring?
Only the inertial force? Or the drag force?

Comment: Draw a free body diagram to figure out how each force contributes to the $F_{\rm net}$ of each body.

Comment: Thank you John for this quite affective answer. I asked myself if in this solution the inertial force is already taken into account. Greetings,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me you are describing the scenario in figure a) below, where *all* the connection forces go through the sensor

[image: fig_a]

But the sensor has two parts, the base and the active part, separated with a little spring. More importantly, each part of the sensor has its own mass as seen below. Also, note the acceleration of each body *is not identical* exactly because of the tiny DOF the sensor introduces since it has the deflect a bit to measure any force.

[image: fig_b]

Now you can do the free-body diagrams to find the equations of motion. Let's assume the motive force acts on the body (1), you have the following FBDs if you ignore friction and make certain assumptions.

[image: fig_c]

with the following $F_{\rm net}=m \,a$ four equations

$$ \begin{aligned}F_{1}-F_{SB} & =m_{1}a_{1}\\
F_{SB}-F_{S} & =m_{SB}a_{1}\\
F_{S}-F_{SA} & =m_{SA}a_{2}\\
F_{SA} & =m_{2}a_{2}
\end{aligned} $$

To be solved for $F_{SA}$, $F_{SB}$, $a_1$ and $a_2$ if $F_1$ and $F_S$ are known.

For example I  get $a_1 = \frac{F_1 - F_S}{m_1 + m_{SB}}$

Alternatively the above can be solved for $F_{SA}$, $F_{SB}$, $F_1$ and $a_2$ if $a_1$ and $F_S$ is known.

For example, I get

$$ F_1 = F_S + a_1 ( m_1 + m_{\rm SB}) $$

So to get your actual answer, you need to create your own FBDs for your situation (including all external forces and friction etc) and solve for the things you want to find out. Also note the orientation of the sensor might differ from the above, given that $m_{SB} > m_{SA}$.

Answer (score 0):

The $F_{resulting}$ is not relevant for the measurements. We could imagine for example an accelerated rocket with several tons, a sensor and a weight of some kg inside. Or after loosing some fuel, a ligther rocket with the same acceleration.

The results of the measurements don't change because the rocket changed its mass, and the engine needs less force to keep the same acceleration.