# Confusion about tension and disk

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, string

[image: Con]

Why are the two tensions not equal? I thought tensions on two ends of a cord are always equal.

And are the motion of the disk caused by friction force due to the motion of the cord and disk surfaces?

Comment: Does "the cord cannot slip" not tell you about the cord-disc friction?  The *axis-disk* is frictionless, but ... Think well lubricated bicycle sprocket...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your two questions are related.  If the pulley has a mass, and we want it to start rotating, then there there must be a net torque on it:
$$
\sum \tau = I \alpha.
$$
The support from the pin does not apply a torque to the pulley (by assumption, it is frictionless) so the torque on the pulley will be
$$
\sum \tau = T_1 R - T_2 R
$$
and we can see that if we want $\alpha \neq 0$ then we must have $T_1 \neq T_2$.

Conversely, for a "massless" pulley, we can treat the moment of inertia $I$ as being negligible.  This then implies that we have to have $(T_1 -T_2)R \approx 0$, or $T_1 \approx T_2$.  If you're taking an introductory physics class, you may have only encountered this case so far, and it may not have been explicitly explained why this was the case;  but now that you know about rotational motion, you can see why the tension in a rope must be constant when the mass of the pulley is very small.

Comment: Is the cause of tension the friction excerted by the cords on the pulley?

Comment: I  had seen another post saying that the forces acting on the two ends of a small section of the cord are equal in magnitude (because the cord is massless). So the tensions at two ends are also equal in magnitude. Why does this not apply here?

Comment: Is it because of friction so that for some segment, the forces that act on it are not just two pulling forces at the two ends?

Comment: @It seems that the forces acting on the disk that cause it to rotate is friction. Why is it that you can relate tensions to the disk as torques?

Comment: @TFR:  Yes, there has to be friction between the rope and the disk for the disc to turn.  This is why the tension is different at the ends of a small section of the cord — the difference in tension between the ends is balanced out by the frictional force.

Comment: @It seems like the only torques that act on the disk are frictions, why can you relate tension to its angular acceleration?

Comment: @TFR:  Each infinitesimal portion of the cord exerts a frictional force on the disk.  Since this force is tangent to the edge of the disk and at a distance $R$, each portion of the cord thereby exerts a torque on the disk.  If you add up all the infinitesimal torques on the disk, they add up to $(T_2 - T_1) R$.  (I encourage you to try to prove this to yourself, or to ask a new question about it if you can't see why this is true.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a related question that tells you why the force is the same if the pulley is massless and rotates without friction. [Why is the tension on both sides of an Atwood machine identical?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/594577/37364)

Typically the pulley is assumed to be massless and frictionless in beginning chapters of a physics class to make the problem simpler. It does make the problem unrealistic, but this kind of problem is hard enough to be instructive without additional complications. Note that the pulley is assumed to turn without friction, but the rope and rim are assumed to have enough friction to make the pulley turn.

In later chapters, you have learn more, and the complication can be added in. If the pulley does have mass and there is enough friction that the rope does not slip, the rope must turn the pulley as the heavier weight descends. Various parts of the pulley accelerate because of the force on the rope.

This is a little like what would happen in the referenced post if there was a mass in the middle of the tug of war. You could calculate the tension in the two halves of the rope. You would find two different values.

It is similar for the rotating pulley, but you calculate the effect of the tensions pulling on the rim with torques and moment of inertia, as Michael Seifert shows.

Answer (score 0):

Because of friction between the cord and the disk, you can think in terms of two separate cords. The tension is the same at each end of each cord, but $T_2$ is greater than $T_1$. Write force equations for each hanging mass, and a torque equation for the disk, You will need to calculate the rotational inertia for the disk.

Comment: It seems that the forces acting on the disk that cause it to rotate is friction. Why is it that you can relate tensions to the disk as torques?

Comment: The torque from each tension  relative to the axle of the disk is TR, one clockwise and the other CCW.

Comment: Is there a tension on the disk? Aren’t there only friction forces?

Comment: The tension is in the cords which exert static friction forces on the disk.

Comment: But the cord is not connected to the disk so there is no tension on the disk?

Comment: The static friction force makes the connection.

Answer (score 0):

> And why can the disk can rotate without friction? If there is no force on it, how can it rotate?

They don't mean that there is no friction between the cord and the disk (it says that the cord cannot slip, so there *is* friction there), but that there's no friction between the disk and the pin/axle (or that it is negligible, so that you can ignore it).

> Why are the two tensions not equal? I thought tensions on two ends of a cord are always equal.

As others have pointed out, since the cord cannot slip (meaning also that it cannot freely stretch and slide over the surface of the disk), it's kind of like it's affixed to the disk (perhaps it's easier to think that way when it's a static situation). There are two separate strands of the cord on each side, and each of them is pulling on the disk, so if you think about it, if both of them pull on the disk with the same force, working against each other, the disk can't begin to turn.

Comment: How does a cord pull on the disk? It is not like attached to it. Is it due to friction?Then the only torques acting on the disk are frictions at every place of contact between the disk and the cord? But why can we relate the tensions of the cords to the disk?

Comment: @TFR "Is it due to friction?" - yes. That's what "the cord cannot slip" means, friction keeps it attached to the surface if you try to move it sideways (tangentially). "But why can we relate the tensions of the cords to the disk?" - not sure what you mean. It's the tension at the ends that ultimately turns the disk (you can think of the section of the cord that's on the disk as being temporarily a part of the disk itself). Tension is just bits of the cord pulling on each other - this causes the cord to stretch, but the segment that lies on the disk is prevented to freely stretch by friction.

Comment: (in this idealized no-slip case)

Comment: @TFR - consider static friction of an object just sitting on a table; you *cannot* move the object with an arbitrarily small force, you have to overcome static friction before it starts to slide (so it's as if it's attached to the table up to that point). Try it yorself with something heavy.

Comment: I guess what's causing your confusion is that you forget that there are two kind of friction - static friction and kinetic friction. There is friction that resits applied force (up to a point) even if there's no relative motion between objects. This static friction is what prevents the cord from slipping on the pulley.

Comment: I have seem others relate the tensions of the cord to the moment of inertia and angular acceleration. It seems like the forces that cause the rotation of the disk are friction forces exerted by the cord on the disk. And there is no tension on the disk because the cord is not attached to it as it is to the two masses. Why?