# Why are these two tension forces equal?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, string

[image]

I am new to this topic and my teacher told me that these two forces in the cable will be equal. I would like to know why this is case.

Comment: The tension forces are equal because there is no friction force between the rope and the pulley. It is rolling without slipping condition.

Comment: Doesn't "frictionless" apply to the pulley axle?

Comment: @Eli make that an answer

Comment: @DJohnM then "light" would come into play - the pulley is very light and takes almost no force to start spinning

Comment: Duplicate question - [Why is the tension on both sides of an Atwood machine identical?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/594577/37364)

Comment: If there is no friction between the rope and the pulley, then why does the pulley rotate in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the tension force along the cable wasn't equal everywhere it would mean the cable would separate into pieces. Imagine the cable consisted of a string of many blocks attached by glue of some sort (see left). You could also imagine them as many sections of rope but for me it's more clear that way. Each block exerts a force on the neighbouring blocks: the tension. If two blocks experience different forces it means that they will experience different acceleration and this will mean the blocks will fly apart or get closer together. So at every junction the forces must balance or otherwise the cable can't be a cable . This argument holds even if the cable is draped over the pulley (see right).

[image]

Comment: Nice answer. Could you please tell me how you drew the diagrams?

Comment: @PhilipWood Thanks! These images were made using Inkscape, which is free.

Comment: For future reference: the part of the cable that is draped over the pulley is slightly more complicated. There could be normal forces and friction forces which makes the forces more complicated if they are present. If the pulley is massless/frictionless we don't need to worry about this.

Comment: @AcccidentalTaylorExpansion Thank you: I'll give Inkscape a try. I used to use [Aldus] Freehand before it was abandoned, which is a hard act to follow. I, too was worried about normal forces etc., which is why I went for virtual work, but this is a bit abstract and not, I'd guess, convincing to a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the easiest way to see this is to use the idea of *work*. Suppose that the lift moves down by distance $D$. Then
$$\text{Work done on rope} = T_{\text{right}} D$$
But the balancing weight will move *up* by the same distance, $D$, so
$$\text{Work done by rope} = T_{\text{left}} D.$$
But there is no gain or loss of energy by the rope or pulley, assuming no friction, and assuming  rope and pulley have negligible mass so KE isn't gained. Therefore there is no net work done by the rope, so
$$T_{\text{left}} D-T_{\text{right}} D=0\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{that is}\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ T_{\text{left}}=T_{\text{right}}.$$

Answer (score 0):

[image]

from the free body diagram

$$m_1\,a_1=-m_1\,g+T_1\\
m_2\,a_2=-m_2\,g+T_2\\
T_1-T_2=0$$

if the rope (length l) is inelastic then

$$z_1+z_2=l\quad \Rightarrow a_1+a_2=0$$

you obtain 4 equations for the 4 unknows $~a_1,a_2,T_1,T2~$ the solution

$$T_1=2\,g\frac{m_1\,m_2}{m_1+m_2}\\
T_2=2\,g\frac{m_1\,m_2}{m_1+m_2}$$

thus $$~T_1\overset{!}{=}T_2$$

---

**with pulley (inertia I)**

[image]

from the free body diagram

$$ I\,\alpha=F_c\,r\\
m_1\,a_1=-m_1\,g+T_1\\
m_2\,a_2=-m_2\,g+T_2\\
T_1-T_2=-F_c$$

and the rolling conditions

$$a_1=\alpha\,r\\
a_2=-\alpha\,r$$

6 equations for 6 unknows. the solution

$$T_1=g\frac{m_1(2\,m_2\,r^2+I)}{m_1\,r^2+m_2\,r^2+I}\\
T_2=g\frac{m_2(2\,m_1\,r^2+I)}{m_1\,r^2+m_2\,r^2+I}$$

thus for $~I=0~$

$$~T_1\overset{!}{=}T_2$$